# Wrapping long bash commands in script files

Tags: command-line, bash, word-wrap

How do you wrap a long command to the next line within a bash script file?

As a simple example, I want to run the command `pushd . && cd /foo/bar && ls && popd`

From the console I can do this:

```
pushd . \
&& cd /foo/bar \
&& ls \
&& popd
```

And that wraps the line. But the same code in a script file produces an error.

How do you wrap these lines to be nicely formatted?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Works fine here. Make sure that the backslash is the very last character on the line, and that the file uses *nix line endings.

Comment: Works fine here too, but so does removing the \'s and &&'s altogether and just leaving the commands on separate lines...

Comment: @elmugrat: But then you lose the conditional chaining.

Comment: Ahhh true... somehow forgot about that.

Comment: this problem was the line endings, which is due to the fact that I'm using cygwin on windows and not a different OS. Thanks.